# How Do I Migrate Tenant Databases and Host Database in Asp.NET ZERO / Boilerplate?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, multi-tenant, entity-framework-migrations, aspnetboilerplate, multi-database

I am using the ASP.NET ZERO framework with ASP.NET Core and Angular for my current project.

I am also using the 'MultiTenancy - MultiDatabase' feature of ASP.Net ZERO.

In application I have added a 'Tenant1-Database' connection string in create new Tenant.

[image]

Now i have two databases:

1. Host-Database
2. Tenant1-Database

When I create a new Tenant, 'Tenant1-Database' is automatically update as per previous migration files.

But when I update the model with a new property and try to migrate the database using code-first approach, I see that 'Host-Database' is the only db migrated with the new properties and Tenant1-Database is not migrated.

My question is: How can I migrate into both databases using a single migration file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yeah.. I Got the Solution**

In the ASP.Net Zero, whole sample template have project with **Projectname.Migrator**

ASP.Net Zero already provides the Host database and all Tenant Databases migrations by console application

Just need to Create a migration file and execute project with **Projectname.Migrator**